# iThemes Security: Hide Login causes website to not load

Tags: wordpress, security, plugins

When logged into my website I had iThemes Security plugin installed and followed the video present in the URL: https://ithemes.com/tutorials/ithemes-security-hide-login-setting-overview/

Login Slug: my-new-login-page

Thus I hid the login to secure my website. Only now when I try to login using the new slug

https://www.mywebsite.com/my-new-login-page

I'm prompted to enter my backend username and password and when I do and click the 'Log In' button nothing happens and I'm presented with a black white screen.

The website URL resolves to: https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-login.php?itsec-hb-token=my-new-login-page

Any ideas anyone please? As I've now locked myself out of my site!

Answer (score 0):

I started researching this issue in more depth, in particular "itsec-hb" and found the following website: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hide-beckend-itsec-hb-token/

So unfortunately this is a catastrophic error and the only way I could recover my website was to kindly ask my hosting provider to restore the latest backup which they did. The downside was that I lost my customers order details in WooCommerce (since they placed orders after the backup was taken) so they could not log into their accounts on my website as they didn't exist on my website.

Important lesson: ALWAYS TAKE A BACKUP OF YOUR SITE BEFORE MAKING ANY SECURITY CHANGES!!!